# Regular Expression alternation in conditional statement

Tags: php, preg-replace, expression

Is there anyway in php to use alternation in a condition as part of a conditional statement? For example:

Imagine I had two backreferences "1" and "2" and needed to check whether either of them existed in order to carry out one of two patterns, like so

```
(?(1|2)foo|bar)
```

I'm using php 5.2.14 so don't have the benefit of escaping backreferences. Everytime I try anything remotely like this I get a compile error...

Is there any possible work-around or is it a case of doing a conditional within a conditional?

Regards

Chris

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx Backreferences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061714/regex-backreferences)

Answer (score 1):

There is no syntax for this I know of. All you can do is:

```
(?(1)foo|(?(2)foo|bar))
```

Comment: As I thought...thanks for your response. Wish there was a cleaner way but nevermind.